NestJS e2e test returning 400 Bad Request, while Postman returns 201 Created for the same endpoint
I am writing an end-to-end test for a NestJS API endpoint that creates a table. The issue is that the test consistently returns a 400 Bad Request, while the same request in Postman works perfectly and returns 201 Created.
Here is the test code I am using:
it('Test #1: Table creation with "name: table | capacity', async () =\> {
const data = {
capacity: 22,
name: 'test',
};
const result = await request
.post('/tables')
.send(data)
.auth(await tokenOwner, { type: 'bearer' })
.expect(201);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(result.statusCode);
console.log(result);
});

Confirmed that the endpoint works in Postman with the exact same payload and authentication.
Verified the token is correct and valid by logging it.
Added console.log to check the payload and response during the test, and the payload appears correct.

It cannot be the exact same - something must be different. Headers?

I found the fix, it was a bit complicated to figure out why it was throwing the error. When I enabled DB logging in the environment, I saw that the 400 error was coming from the database, not the endpoint as I initially thought. The subscriber for the table is supposed to generate a slug that gets saved in the DB. However, in the testing environment, the subscriber never reached that part to generate the slug and it remained null. Since it can't stay null, it returns a 400 error with an empty message. I enabled the TableSubscriber to run in the test and everything is working as expected now.
